# TypeORM not returning all records

Tags: node.js, oracle, typeorm, sveltekit

I am developing a web page with node.js + Sveltekit + TypeORM + Oracle.
When I ran a query with TypeORM's `find` method that resulted in 847 rows, only 10 were retrieved.
When I run the SQL displayed in the log in Oracle SQL Developer, I get 847 records.
I did not specify the `take` or `skip` options for the `find` method.
When I get the count with `findAndCount`, it comes out as 847, so it seems that pagination is being done arbitrarily.
How can I get all rows?